# How to get the class name in ActiveSupport::Concern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have classes User, Product and Order. I have a common concern Logger which I have included in each. I have a after_create callback in the Logger module which will log the creation. I need the different type of class names with the log there.

```
class User
  include Logger
  attr_accessor :name
end

class Product
  include Logger
  attr_accessor :name
end

class Order
  include Logger
  attr_accessor :name
end
```

I have the logger module

```
module Logger
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    after_create :log_event
  end

  def log_event
    puts "#{<some way to get name of the class>} created now."
  end 
end
```

I want "some way to get name of the class" there. I have tried self.name (returns the value in the name attribute of the class), self.class.name (returns Class), self.downcase (return error), self.table_name (return error). Please let me know the solution to this. It is imperative that I don't change this structure too much too.

Comment: What is the output of `puts self.inspect` in the `log_event` method in the context of the creation of an object using the Logger module?

Comment: It gives the User object like <xUser: h188b12hjh>

Comment: then `self` represents the User instance (in that case). `self.class` should return User

Answer (score 4):

You can use just `self.name` instead of `self.class` or `self.class.name` when using concerns.

Example:

```
def log_event
  puts "#{self.name} created now."
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The same way you would get it in a normal instance method.

```
def log_event
  puts "#{self.class} created now."
end
```

You can do `self.class.name` also.

Comment: this gives the User object string

Comment: You would get `Class` as output if you are calling `.class` on `User` instead of an object of `User`

Comment: Can you post exact method and class definitions(the one posted don't have AR inheritance) or try with `pry` or `byebug` in this method. `self` should be pointing to the user object being created

Comment: @PiKaY this should work. If you're getting `users` from `self.class.table_name` then `self.class.name` should be `User`. Just to be 100% sure, I tested your module myself. Please post more of your class definitions, there must be something wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer to this. I can use self.class.table_name to get the name as users, products etc. i.e. if the table name is not custom

Comment: `self.class.table_name` would work only if `self.class` gets resolved to `User` or `Product`. It doesn't sound right that `self.class.table_name` works but `self.class` doesn't.